# Remove 0's after decimal point in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Remove 0's at the end of decimal point in **XSLT** like if 7.40 then 7.4.
and 7.0 then 7.
Like G29 format in c#.

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: thanks Danny I keep in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
format-number(.,'#,##0.########')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the XPath [number() function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-number).